# Android - Open Data Socket, Continuously Write to Text View (Read Data)

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, client-server

I am currently working off of two great TCP/IP Client examples. My goal is to create a simple TCP/IP Client that connects to a server and, once a connection is established, continuously updates a TextView with strings passed from the server. If the user presses a button, the client sends a stop command to the server and I would ultimately like to expand the TextView into a graph with the converted string values. I am able to establish the connection to the server and send the stop command from the client but my attempts at adding the read capability have, so far, been unsuccessful with the app crashing as soon as it starts up.

Here are the links to the examples I've been using for guidance:

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/02/android-sercerclient-example-client.html

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/08/bi-directional-communication-between.html

Here is the code in my MainActivity:

```
package com.example.androidclient;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView            textResponse;
    TextView            textIn;
    EditText            editTextAddress, editTextPort; 
    Button              buttonConnect, buttonStopTest, buttonDisconnect;
    Socket              socket              = null;
    DataInputStream     incomingString      = null;
    DataOutputStream    terminalLetter      = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        editTextAddress     = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);
        editTextPort        = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.port);
        buttonConnect       = (Button)findViewById(R.id.connect);
        buttonDisconnect    = (Button)findViewById(R.id.disconnect);
        buttonStopTest      = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop_test);
        textResponse        = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.response);
        textIn              = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_in);

        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(buttonConnectOnClickListener);

        buttonStopTest.setOnClickListener(buttonStopTestOnClickListener);

        buttonDisconnect.setOnClickListener(buttonDisconnectOnClickListener);
    }

    OnClickListener buttonConnectOnClickListener = new OnClickListener(){
        //setOnClickListener sets a callback to be invoked when the button is clicked
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //Clicking button (Connect) calls a MyClientTask defined below. 
            MyClientTask myClientTask = new     
            MyClientTask(editTextAddress.getText().toString(),   
            Integer.parseInt(editTextPort.getText().toString()));
            myClientTask.execute();
        }
    };

    OnClickListener buttonStopTestOnClickListener = new OnClickListener(){
        //setOnClickListener sets a callback to be invoked when the button is clicked
        @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                try {
                    terminalLetter = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    terminalLetter.writeByte('b');
                    terminalLetter.writeByte('\n');
                    terminalLetter.close();
                    socket.close();
                } 
                catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection.");
                }
            }
    };

    OnClickListener buttonDisconnectOnClickListener = new OnClickListener(){
        //setOnClickListener sets a callback to be invoked when the button is clicked
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };


    public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        String IPaddress;
        int Port;
        String response = "";

        MyClientTask(String addr, int port){
        IPaddress = addr;
        Port = port;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        //Took socket declaration from here. 

        try {
            //Taking relevant parameters and applying them to socket
            socket = new Socket(IPaddress, Port);                
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;

            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

            incomingString = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            textIn.setText(incomingString.readUTF());

            /*
             * notice:
             * inputStream.read() will block if no data return
             */
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
            }
        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
        }
        finally{
            if(socket != null){
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } 
                catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        textResponse.setText(response);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}

}
```

I put the commands for reading data from the server and writing it to the TextView with the code that sets up the connection to the socket. The idea was that it would be the next step after the connection is established but I realize that it looks like I am only reading once. I tried adding a while loop and bringing it out of the doInBackground. In each case, all I got was the whole app crashing on me. It looks fairly straight forward in the example but there the connection is automatic, not triggered and I have not been able to modify the code successfully.

I am still new to Android and this feels like it is an important part of app development so I am hoping someone in the community can help me understand where the section of code relevant to reading data (continuously) should be placed in relation to the rest.

Best, 
Yusif Nurizade

P.S. I was going to include the fragment but previous postings had some people suggesting it was not necessary. Since the post is long enough, I chose to omit it but can share upon request.

Comment: What's the error message? Where is your logcat?

Comment: I recommend to take a look at services instead of async task..

Comment: Loma, thank you for the reply. I ran the program again and it hasn't been crashing. I moved around code while I was trying to get it to work so the crash may have been remedied. Do you still want me to post the logcat?


In any case the TextView is still not showing me the string. I am curious if this is an issue of the code commands or their placement in the code? Also, could you elaborate on the services vs. async task?

Comment: Async task is used for long running operations (to avoid blocking the main thread -UI thread). But the term long running doesnt mean infinite.. In other words, downloading a file is cool, chat isnt cool. For these kind of operations where something is supposed to run for a very long time (more than a few seconds) it is advised to use services, as they are less likely to be killed by the OS.